# Drupal 7 I need to replace images in files system and also replace over S3 bucket without changing url of image over S3

Tags: amazon-s3, drupal-7

Drupal 7 I need to replace images in files system and also replace over S3 bucket without changing url of image over S3.

I am using s3fs module for upload images over S3.

Comment: Please write your questions clearly. "I need to replace images in files system" does this mean within your drupal root `<drupal_root>/sites/default/files/...`?? 
and you also have files at S3 bucket as well which you want replaced without  the url changed ??

Comment: I need to updated the files which is already uploaded in Drupal (using s3fs module with s3fs-public folder setting, where if we upload load any images on Drupal "<drupal_root>/sites/default/files/" its directly upload over S3 and no copy save on local "<drupal_root>/sites/default/files/"  folder ). 

I got issues if I uploaded the files it not replace the files over S3 bucket and not create style images over S3 bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Granting Cross-Account Permissions to Upload Objects While Ensuring the Bucket Owner Has Full Control

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
     {
       "Sid":"111",
       "Effect":"Allow",
       "Principal":{"AWS":"1111111111"},
       "Action":"s3:PutObject",
       "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"
     },
     {
       "Sid":"112",
       "Effect":"Deny",
       "Principal":{"AWS":"1111111111" },
       "Action":"s3:PutObject",
       "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
       "Condition": {
         "StringNotEquals": {"s3:x-amz-grant-full-control":["emailAddress=xyz@amazon.com"]}
       }
     }
   ]
}
```

For detail please check [Granting Cross-Account Permissions to Upload Objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-8)

Comment: Thanks for your support

Comment: @user8550844 :) wc